# How to reorder the plot by factors in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder the `geom_col` plot by one of the factors `pct_female_vacc` used below in plot of the variable `pct_vacc_GenderType`.

**df**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(gganimate)

file_url1 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/cowin_vaccine_data_statewise.csv"

df_vaccination <- read.csv(url(file_url1))

df_vaccination <- df_vaccination %>%
  mutate(Updated.On = as.Date(Updated.On))
```

**plot**

```
df_vaccination %>% 
  filter(State != "India",
         Updated.On == max(Updated.On)) %>% 
  # arrange(desc(Updated.On)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_female_vacc = Female.Individuals.Vaccinated./Total.Individuals.Vaccinated,
         pct_male_vacc = Male.Individuals.Vaccinated./Total.Individuals.Vaccinated,
         
         State = as.factor(State)
         ) %>%
  
  pivot_longer(cols = c(pct_female_vacc:pct_male_vacc),
               names_to = "pct_vacc_GenderType",
               values_to = "pct_vacc") %>% 
  mutate(pct_vacc_GenderType = as.factor(pct_vacc_GenderType)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = pct_vacc, y =  State , 
             fill = pct_vacc_GenderType)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

I am looking to get above plot to be **reordered** by **red color** i.e `pct_female_vacc` factor.

Unable to use `reorder_within` as I have not used `facet_wrap` here. Also tried `fct_reorder` but may be I am not doing it right or even that doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Your plot is not reproducible. Would you please check your code? :)

Comment: @RonakShah  ... apoligies it was an issue with the github file. I have changed the url with the correct file.

Comment: @bird ... apoligies it was an issue with the github file. I have changed the url with the correct file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrange` the data by `pct_female_vacc` and change the `State` to factor based on appearance.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_vaccination %>% 
  filter(State != "India",
         Updated.On == max(Updated.On)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_female_vacc = `Female.Individuals.Vaccinated.`/Total.Individuals.Vaccinated,
         pct_male_vacc = Male.Individuals.Vaccinated./Total.Individuals.Vaccinated) %>%
  arrange(pct_female_vacc) %>%
  mutate(State = factor(State, unique(State))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(pct_female_vacc:pct_male_vacc),
               names_to = "pct_vacc_GenderType",
               values_to = "pct_vacc") %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = pct_vacc, y =  State , 
             fill = pct_vacc_GenderType)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I didn't know it will retain the order from arrange even after pivoting !!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is simple with `forcats::fct_reorder`. The only thing you have to be cautious about is that you need to set the factor before `pivot_longer`. Here you go:

```r
df_vaccination %>% 
  filter(State != "India",
         Updated.On == max(Updated.On) - 1) %>% # the newest date contains only NAs, so I use the second oldest
  # arrange(desc(Updated.On)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_female_vacc = Female.Individuals.Vaccinated./Total.Individuals.Vaccinated,
         pct_male_vacc = Male.Individuals.Vaccinated./Total.Individuals.Vaccinated,
         
         State = as.factor(State)
  ) %>%
  mutate(State = forcats::fct_reorder(State, pct_female_vacc)) %>% # since you pivot longer in the next step you have to order your factors here
  pivot_longer(cols = c(pct_female_vacc:pct_male_vacc),
               names_to = "pct_vacc_GenderType",
               values_to = "pct_vacc") %>% 
  mutate(pct_vacc_GenderType = as.factor(pct_vacc_GenderType)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(pct_vacc)) %>% # use this instead of na.omit() to remove NAs
  
  ggplot(aes(x = pct_vacc, y =  State , 
             fill = pct_vacc_GenderType)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") # I moved the legend to the bottom so it looks better on for stackoverflow
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @JBGruber, your answer worked perfectly but I accepted other person's answer as he was trying even before when the github file link was broken. But I am highly impressed with the details you have put in and used a date prior to max date. Thanks again for the help & effort. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Yeah, no worries! I used the original link and fixed the problem with `max(Updated.On) - 1` though ;)